# Convertir QString a char

Tags: c++, qt

¿Cómo se convierte un `QString` a `char`? algún modo facil y comprensible?

Es para entenderlo mejor gracias.

Comment: Verificar este enlace [Qt string to char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion "Qt string ti char") Espero te sirva

Comment: El método toStdString() puede ayudarte, revisa la respuesta de @eferion.

Comment: si me ayudo mucho super facil de entender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QString` dispone del método `toStdString()` que te devuelve un `std::string`. Obtener un `char` a partir de este objeto es trivial:

```
QString cadena = "Hola";
std::string cadenaStd = cadena.toStdString();
char c = cadenaStd[0];
std::cout << c;
```

Un saludo.

Comment: me resolvistes dos problemas en uno

Comment: Si te ayudo esta respuesta, marcarla como "correcta" por favor Omar!. =)

Answer (score 1):

#### Pregunta.

> ¿Cómo se convierte un `QString` a `char`?

No existe conversión posible de un tipo complejo (en este caso `QString`) a un tipo fundamental (en este caso `char`), tu pregunta es parecida a "*¿Cómo se convierte un [Coche](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autom%C3%B3vil_de_turismo) en un [Pistón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pist%C3%B3n)?*".

Si bien es cierto que los Coches tienen motores y los motores tienen Pistones, un Pistón es una parte del Coche.

No puedes *convertir* un Coche en un Pistón aunque usarás Pistones para construír tu Coche... paralelamente no puedes *convertir* un `QString` en un `char` aunque usarás `char` como pieza de un `QString`.

Así que supongo que en realidad querías preguntar:

> ¿Cómo accedo a los `char` de un `QString`?

Por lo que voy a basar mi respuesta en esa suposición.

#### Aclaración.

[`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) está creado como clase análoga a la clase [string](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string); así pues dispone de métodos parecidos, equivalentes o exáctamente iguales.

#### Sugerencia.

Usa el operador de indexado (acceso mediante corchetes `[` y `]`). Dada la casi completa equivalencia entre `QString` y `std::string` ambos objetos disponen de dicho operador y se usa de la misma manera.

- [`QString::operator []`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-5b-5d).
- [`std::string::operator []`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Así que, en el siguiente ejemplo, ambos muestran `@` al usar el
   operador corchetes sobre la quinta posición:

```
QString       q_mail("hola@mundo.com");
std::string stl_mail("hola@mundo.com");

std::cout << "quinto caracter: " <<   q_mail[4];
std::cout << "quinto caracter: " << stl_mail[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues asumiendo que usas Qt 5.x, es relativamente simple.

Para convertir uno a uno (o algunos) de los caracteres de un `QString` tendrías que usar algo como el siguiente código:

```cpp
 QString ejemplo="ejemplo";
 std::cout << ejemplo.at(0).toLatin1(); //funcion at devuelve el tipo de dato Qchar de la cadena en la posicion 0
 //y .toLatin1() devuelve el caracter en dato char.
```

En cambio si quieres convertir todo el `QString`, una opción mas rápida es usar `.toLatin1()` sobre el objeto `QString`.

```cpp
 QString ejemplo2="ejemplo2";
 ejemplo2.toLatin1(); //esta funcion devuelve un QByteArray
```

Un `QByteArray` es a groso modo una clase que sirve como un arreglo dinamico de `char` (puedes concatenar, agregar, quitar, etc.), sin la complejidad de la memoria dinámica.

Además hay que decir que de un `QByteArray` puedes obtener el dato como tipo `char` si usas las funciones `data` o `constData`.

```cpp
 QByteArray ejemploByteArray=ejemplo2.toLatin1();
 ejemploByteArray.constData(); //devuelve un puntero constante a un data *char, por ejemplo si solo es un parametro de lectura
 ejemploByteArray.data(); //devuelve un puntero  *char, este si modificable, por lo que si lo manipulas cambiaras tambien los datos de QByteArray, por lo que aqui si hay que tener cuidado.
```